# Angular: Can't bind to 'file' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, typescript

I've two input elements in my component.html

```
<input type="file" ngf [(files)]="files" multiple  />
  <input type="file" ngf [(file)]="file" />
```

The first one is working perfectly whereas the second one is resulting in error `Can't bind to 'file' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.` I've imported ngfModule from "angular-file" in my module.ts file. I'm following this website https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file and I couldn't figure out what is the problem? How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this-

```
<input type="file" ngf [(files)]="files" multiple  />
<input type="file" ngf [(files)]="file" />
```